# Update referencing on subquery (sqlite)

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, exists

I have a table with md5 sums for files and use the following query to find the files which exist in one hashing-run and not in the other (oldt vs newt):

```
SELECT *
FROM md5_sums as oldt
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM md5_sums as newt
                  WHERE oldt.file = newt.file
                  and oldt.relpath = newt.relpath
                  and newt.starttime = 234)
and oldt.starttime = 123
```

now I want to put a flag in an extra column with an update clause, like

```
update md5_sums
set only_in_old = 'X'
where
```

and there I want a reference to the upper query as subquery, but i cannot find a proper way. Is there a possibility to use the results from the upper query for the where clause from the update-query?
(I added now some Table Screenshots with simple Table Data)

Table Description
[image: Table Description]

Table Data before UPDATE
[image: Table Data before UPDATE]

desired Table Data after UPDATE
[image: desired Table Data after UPDATE]

Comment: Give us sample tables and expected result please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support aliasing the updated table.
In your case you don't need that. 
You can use the table's name `md5_sums` inside the subquery since you aliased the table of the `SELECT` statement as `newt`.

```
UPDATE md5_sums 
SET only_in_old = 'X'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM md5_sums AS newt
  WHERE md5_sums.file = newt.file
  AND md5_sums.relpath = newt.relpath
  AND newt.starttime = 234
)
AND starttime = 123
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/55VVvsfZ3qDXyBs4iXjVFo/1).
Results:

```
| file    | relpath  | starttime | only_in_old |
| ------- | -------- | --------- | ----------- |
| abc.txt | /var/tmp | 123       |             |
| abc.txt | /var/tmp | 234       |             |
| def.txt | /tmp     | 123       | X           |
| xyz.txt | /tmp     | 234       |             |
```

Comment: this doesn't work like expected. The row with file = "abc.txt" and relpath = "/var/tmp" get's an "X" too, but this row exists for the old (123) and the new starttime (234)

Comment: Did you check the demo? It works for the sample data and the conditions you posted. The only row that gets checked is `def.txt /tmp 123`.

Comment: sorry my mistake - my test-db had an error now it works

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you in converting the select statement into an update statement,

```
UPDATE md5_sums 
SET only_in_old = 'X'

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM md5_sums newt
                  WHERE file = newt.file
                  and relpath = newt.relpath
                  and newt.starttime = 1551085649.7764235)
and starttime = 1551085580.009046
```

Comment: doing this i get a syntax error near .  - i think you could not use the alias in the update statement

Comment: Hi can you try now, I didn't use an alias.